# how to overwrite existing pdf file using FPDF

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf, overwrite

I have a problem, I want to overwrite an existing pdf file. This is what I want to do, when I update something in my system like for example: I insert new data in the database, there must be a automatic download (I think it's d or f in fpdf) in a specific path (C://pdf_folders) and the existing pdf file (oyeah.pdf) must be updated or overwrite the content.

How can I do this? Please help me. :(

Answer (score 3):

You need to delete file if it exists

```
if (file_exists('oyeah.pdf')) {
    unlink('oyeah.pdf');
}
$pdf->Output('oyeah.pdf', 'FD');
```